# Design a card with linear gradient in a triangular shape in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, linear-gradients

I have a card which contains an image of the prodcut and product details above the image i.e in the Stack.

[image: Product Card]

Problem is with the gradient design which is like a triangular shape i.e

[image: Linear Gradient Required]

I have tried using Linear Gradient inside Box Decoration of a container widget like this :

```
Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: 141,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    end: Alignment.topRight,
                    colors: [Colors.black, Color(0x00000000)],
                  ),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  // Data inside Column
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

but did't work.

Comment: I could not understand what you want, what is the problem here?

Comment: I want to add a gradient  color behind the text just like in the image which starts from the bottom left

Answer (score 1):

You should add where the gradient starts and ends, which you did, but you forgot the parameter `stops: [0.7, 1]` give whatever numbers you want from 0 to 1.

If that does not work, try changing colors to this `colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent]`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can add more color transparent and add custom Alignment

example :

```
Container(
                height: 300,
                width: 300,
                decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  gradient:const LinearGradient(
                    begin:Alignment(-0.1, 1),
                    end: Alignment.topRight,
                    colors: [Colors.yellow, Colors.transparent,Colors.transparent,Colors.transparent,],
                  ),
                ),
            )
```